# How do I rig my 3d model properly? Parenting isn't working for me

Tags: modeling, rigging, parent

Im new to rigging in blender, I want to pose this model I made but i cant, even after watching multiple videos after making the armature posing it doesnt work after parenting.[image: This is before parenting it is my scene colection out of place? Any directions will be greatly apreciated.]

[image: This image is after selecting the Rig, Shift selecting the model, parenting with automatic weights, and moving a bone(to see if it works)]

This problem may have already been solved but i cant find an answer. Im open to DM via discord or if somebody can guide me here, even better. All help is apreciated ive been dealing with this for too long. If anybody needs more specific images of my UI for context just tell me and ill try to be as fast as posible to not waste anybody's time.

Comment: Difficult to tell without more details, but from the outliner it looks as if it's not been parented correctly. I suggest you view [this short video](https://youtu.be/l9eR_S0QQ4E?t=51) from CGDive which shows exactly how it's supposed to be done. - The Automatic Weights section is the one you'll need but it's worth viewing all of it, particularly how it's supposed to look in the outliner when it's parented correctly.

Comment: I recommend watching this playlist from CGDive it helps me a lot and helps me to rig the dragon model I recommend watching from the beginning of the playlist.https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLdcL5aF8ZcJv68SSdwxip33M7snakl6Dx